# Finding a laptop lost while on board a flight?

Tags: lost-luggage, spirit-airlines

I flew from Dallas to Las Vegas today and left my laptop in the seat pocket. Unfortunately, I did not realize this fact until after I took another connecting flight and got home.

As this was a Spirit Airlines flight, the first thing I did was call up customer care and register a claim on their website. Subsequently, I’ve been trying to find information from the local lost and found at LAS, Spirit’s baggage claim center, and through the LAS website. However, it’s been more than 8 hours since the flight landed, so I’m wondering if the laptop probably never got picked up by the ground handling staff.

Now, I’ve been scratching my head in trying to optimize my search.

1. I know the arrival gate, so I’m wondering if I should find subsequent outbound flights from the same gate (flight). Can the same flight have another number for a different journey? How do I find it?
2. I’ve not been able to find the location of my laptop through the location service from Apple. Any suggestions?
3. In general, what else can I try doing? I’m honestly devastated, so I’d really appreciate any valuable advice.

Comment: You can use services such as Flightradar24 or FlightAware to look up the actual aircraft used for your flight and from there all subsequent flights flown by that aircraft.

Comment: Is this the plane you flew in? https://www.flightradar24.com/data/aircraft/n639nk

Comment: @meego : thank you for taking a look. It was a different flight. On searching, I only see subsequent scheduled flights on the same route, not other routes taken by the same flight.

Comment: @jcaron, thanks for sharing some pointers. I searched both websites and I only see upcoming, en-route and past flights for the route between DFW and LAS. Cannot find other routes this aircraft has taken after it landed at LAS. Can you share any other suggestions, please?

Comment: I think you can forget to try to follow the physical plane, because the next person sitting in that seat grabbed the laptop or reported it. It will not be any longer in the plane. If the airline doesn’t have it, consider it gone.

Comment: @Aganju, thanks. I’m devastated with my carelessness. Would it make sense to contact to local law enforcement as they could try following up with the airline about the next person sitting in the plane?

Comment: My experience is that they wouldn't do a thing even if you had a video of a guy stealing it and his name (happened to me). No time, more important things to do, whatever. If the airline doesn't have it, get used to the idea of a total loss.

Comment: On Flightradar24, search for your flight, then click on the tail number (N639NK or something similar), you’ll get the flight history for that aircraft, but that’s 4 to 6 flights a day, not sure if that will help a lot. Was Find My Mac enabled? What’s the last location report time? Have you activated “Mark as lost”? However the issue with MacBooks is that they will report location only if they connect to WiFi (so they need to be in reach of a network you already connected to and is open), which makes it a lot less useful than for iPhones or cellular iPads.

Comment: Actually if you are running Catalina or a more recent macOS version and have another Apple device on the same iCloud account you may be able to get a “crowdsourced” location for your Mac even without WiFi as long as there are other Apple devices nearby. Not sure if that works with all MacBooks, though, and I never tried it.

Comment: Note that if you find it, report it to law enforcement. Don’t try to get it back yourself from whoever has it (unless of course it points to the lost and found desk!)

Comment: Thank you so much, @jcaron. Really appreciate you providing your insight. The laptop was on the "Find my" list. I can see details of other devices on my list, but the laptop reads "No location found". I initiated the lock mechanism to display a message on the screen, but the request is "pending" since yesterday afternoon. Not sure what else I could do at this point.

Comment: @Aganju Yes. I had a laptop stolen on a Cathay Pacific flight. They were not willing to do anything. Horrible experience.